# Noughts, Crosses, Question marks, and Ouroboros

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

In the following diagram, identify the symbols that go to the position marked as `****`. Each arrow implies a specific relationship between its head and its tail.

```
+------> OXOO -------+
|                    |
|                    v
O?O?              ?XXO
^                    |
|                    |
|   **** ---> OOOO   |
|                    |
|                    |
+-- X??O <--- ?X?? <-+
```

Hint 1:

> A question mark (?) is just a symbol like an O or an X. It isn't something that hides another symbol.

Hint 2:

> Commonly the symbol O means correct, and X means incorrect. The question mark means somewhere in between. But these meanings apply to only one (consistent) end of each arrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> `X?O? -> OOOO`

Method:

Each set of 4 symbols represents

> A guess in a game of [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). The opponent has a hidden sequence of 4 symbols.

Following round the arrows, the next set of 4 symbols represents

> The response from the opponent.

Specifically:

> `O` represents a guessed symbol that was in the right place
>  `X` represents a guessed symbol that does not appear
>  `?` represents a guessed symbol that does appear, but not in the location stated
>  The goal of the game is to guess the correct set of symbols in the correct order, i.e. to get a response of `OOOO`

Working through the individual clues:

1. `OXOO -> ?XXO` tells us

> there are either exactly two `O` and no `X` in the final solution, or exactly one `O` and at least one `X`. Exactly one of the correct symbols is in the right place.

2. `?XXO -> ?X??` tells us

> either all 3 symbols are in the final solution with exactly one `X`, or there are no `?` and at least two `X`

3. `?X?? -> X??O` tells us

> either there are 3 `?` in the final solution, or exactly two `?` and at least one `X`. Taken with the preceding two clues, the final solution would appear to be a permutation of `??XO`, with one of the `?` in position 2 (as one was in the wrong place, and this is the only position that a `?` was not guessed)

4. `X??O -> O?O?` tells us

> the previous conclusion was indeed correct. Two symbols are in the right place, the other two must be swapped, and we know position 2 is correct. Permutations fitting this with 1 swap: `??XO` violates clue 2, `O??X` or `X?O?` work so far.

5. `O?O? -> OXOO` tells us

> The final solution must look like `*?O?` or `O?*?`. Only one of the permutations that had worked for the previous clues matches this pattern.

Rechecking what we learned so far

> `X?O?` seems to be the correct pattern, so
>  `OXOO -> ?XXO` (`X` in wrong place, one `O` in right place, no second or third `O`)
>  `?XXO -> ?X??` (`X`, `O`, and `?` all in wrong place, no second `x`)
>  `?X?? -> X??O` (final `?` in right place, other `?` and `X` in wrong place, no third `?`)
>  `X??O -> O?O?` (`X` and one `?` in right place, `O` and other `?` in wrong place)
>  `O?O? -> OXOO` (`*?O?` is fully correct, but no second `O`)

Which confirms the final answer.

Comment: Perfect, you got it.